# aws lambda describe autoscaling group instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to get all instance ids of a particular autoscaling group for that I think the below code must work...but it returns only the tags of all instances in that autoscaling group...Why I am not getting the instance IDs?
Boto3 document shows that using this code we can get whole information of group,but I am getting only tags...what is the way to solve this problem?

```
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
    def lambda_handler(event, context):

       response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
       AutoScalingGroupNames=['tryautoscalegroup']
       )   

       print(response)
```

Comment: Could you please share the redacted output you receive when you run this lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that is in your code perfectly works for your use case, i.e, it is giving all the details of that autoscaling group, that means it is giving all the instnaces and its loadbalancer and autoscaling configuration information. Pointing to your question, you would want to have the instance id's only which will be possible by parsing the response that you are getting after the `describe_auto_scaling_groups(**kwargs)` function.
Then From that you can get the instance ids by parsing the json response like `response["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"]`
and below is thw whole lambda function which will print the instance ids of your autoscaling group.

```
import boto3
asg = boto3.client('autoscaling')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   response = asg.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
   AutoScalingGroupNames=['myasgname']
   )   

   print(response)
   instances=response["AutoScalingGroups"][0]["Instances"]
   #declare a empty list so that later we can append instance ids into this list
   instanceids=[]
   for i in instances:
      instanceids.append(i["InstanceId"])
   print instanceids
```

Here down below is the exapmle of your response json:

```
{
    'AutoScalingGroups': [
        {
            'AutoScalingGroupName': 'string',
            'AutoScalingGroupARN': 'string',
            'LaunchConfigurationName': 'string',
            'LaunchTemplate': {
                'LaunchTemplateId': 'string',
                'LaunchTemplateName': 'string',
                'Version': 'string'
            },
            'MinSize': 123,
            'MaxSize': 123,
            'DesiredCapacity': 123,
            'DefaultCooldown': 123,
            'AvailabilityZones': [
                'string',
            ],
            'LoadBalancerNames': [
                'string',
            ],
            'TargetGroupARNs': [
                'string',
            ],
            'HealthCheckType': 'string',
            'HealthCheckGracePeriod': 123,
            'Instances': [
                {
                    'InstanceId': 'string',
                    'AvailabilityZone': 'string',
                    'LifecycleState': 'Pending'|'Pending:Wait'|'Pending:Proceed'|'Quarantined'|'InService'|'Terminating'|'Terminating:Wait'|'Terminating:Proceed'|'Terminated'|'Detaching'|'Detached'|'EnteringStandby'|'Standby',
                    'HealthStatus': 'string',
                    'LaunchConfigurationName': 'string',
                    'LaunchTemplate': {
                        'LaunchTemplateId': 'string',
                        'LaunchTemplateName': 'string',
                        'Version': 'string'
                    },
                    'ProtectedFromScaleIn': True|False
                },
            ],
            'CreatedTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'SuspendedProcesses': [
                {
                    'ProcessName': 'string',
                    'SuspensionReason': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'PlacementGroup': 'string',
            'VPCZoneIdentifier': 'string',
            'EnabledMetrics': [
                {
                    'Metric': 'string',
                    'Granularity': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Status': 'string',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'ResourceId': 'string',
                    'ResourceType': 'string',
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string',
                    'PropagateAtLaunch': True|False
                },
            ],
            'TerminationPolicies': [
                'string',
            ],
            'NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn': True|False,
            'ServiceLinkedRoleARN': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
```

Comment: if you have multiple instances on your autoscaling group, you could use for loop, to loop among the dict of instances. I updated the code in answer. take a look at.